# How to get last class by Jquery

Tags: jquery

my class is like this;

```
<div class="card-box non-clickable offer"></div>
```

and I just want to get offer class  I don't want to get before offer what should I do ?

my functions is like this

```
$(".card-box").on("click",function(){
var get_cls = $(this).attr("class");
alert(get_cls);
});
```

print;

> card-box non-clickable offer

but it must be just

> offer

Comment: Are you trying to check if there is class `offer` in the clicked element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use spilt() function:

split() will split the entire string into array and pop() will rerturn last element thats offers

```
$(".card-box").on("click",function(){
   var get_cls = $(this).attr("class");
   var answer = get_cls.split(" ").pop();
   alert(answer);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If offer class is always last in class attribute then split based on space and get last element from array. So **[`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** method can be used here.

```js
$(".card-box").on("click", function() {
  var get_cls = $(this).attr("class")
    .split(' ') // split class names
    .pop(); // pop out last element from array
  alert(get_cls);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-box non-clickable offer">c</div>
```